# What are the prerequisites for working on multi agent systems?

Tags: distributed-systems, agent-based-computing

I am starting to study about **Multi Agent Systems** and I wanted to know which sciences are most used in these systems, I am aware of game theory and Markov statistical relations ([Markov Decision Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_decision_process) and [Markov Hidden Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model)).
But I am not aware of all.If someone could name them for me it would be appreciated.

I also want to know the Major Journals On Multi Agent Systems.I have been trying to find them according to the Impact Factors but it seems it's not a good measure for doing so (Because there are some tricks for increasing the impact factor and cheating that journals do).

Comment: A reference request like yours is too broad for Stack Exchange -- you ask for a survey of a whole research area! You need to narrow your focus considerably before a question of reasonable scope appears. Try talking to your advisor(s), search with [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=some+query) and check out [this guide to better (re)searches](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/13594/1419) on [academia.SE].

Comment: I recommend you start reading about Multi Agent Systems, and whenever you don't understand something hit the given reference (or ask here). Recurse.

Comment: @Raphael I have asked this question here because I have no access to an advisor who is an expert or professor in this field to guide me and about that you have said question is too broad, I have asked the same question in other field from my lecturers and it's a very short answer they name 5 to 10 major journals to you and name at most 10 prerequisites for understanding multi agent systems I don't know why you are saying it's off topic or it needs a very long answer. There is no where on the internet that gives people such information.

Comment: If they name journals as prerequisites, they are probably wrong. Ten prerequisites is already a lot, if you reason them out, and I'll wager that if you ask five people you'll get forty in total. Besides, this is a list question; we don't have a strict policy for list questions, but there is a [general dislike](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/). Please note also [this](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/20) and [this](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/145/) discussion. (If you think closing was unjustified, feel free to flag or open a thread n meta.)